# Heap corruption - Vector push_back

Tags: c++, heap-corruption, memory-corruption

I seem to have a corrupted heap, I cannot figure out why this is happening....

Following is the trace from valgrind..

```
==12697== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==12697==    at 0xDD0725: __gnu_cxx::__atomic_add(int volatile*, int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.7)
==12697==    by 0x1C3AD9BB: chargeRate::chargeRate(chargeRate const&) (in /root//app/libapp++.so)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C9C22: __gnu_cxx::__mt_alloc_base<chargeRate>::construct(chargeRate*, chargeRate const&) (mt_allocator.h:585)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAC9F: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<chargeRate*, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> > >, chargeRate const&) (vector.tcc:284)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAF9E: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::push_back(chargeRate const&) (stl_vector.h:610)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8A03: WebTranslations::getChargeDetails(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:427)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8F83: WebTranslations::getChargeTranslations(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:1172)

==12697== 
==12697== Invalid read of size 4
==12697==    at 0xDB468B: std::string::string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.7)
==12697==    by 0x1C3AD9E0: chargeRate::chargeRate(chargeRate const&) (in /root//app/libapp++.so)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C9C22: __gnu_cxx::__mt_alloc_base<chargeRate>::construct(chargeRate*, chargeRate const&) (mt_allocator.h:585)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAC9F: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<chargeRate*, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> > >, chargeRate const&) (vector.tcc:284)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAF9E: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::push_back(chargeRate const&) (stl_vector.h:610)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8A03: WebTranslations::getChargeDetails(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:427)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8F83: WebTranslations::getChargeTranslations(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:1172)
==12697==    by 0x1C299E48: zif__get_charge_translations (in /usr/lib/php4/.so)
==12697==    by 0x1BCE0916: zend_do_fcall_common_helper (in /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==12697==    by 0x1BCF1088: zend_do_fcall_handler (in /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==12697==    by 0x1BCDDD92: execute (in /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==12697==    by 0x1BCE02A9: zend_do_fcall_common_helper (in /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so)
==12697==  Address 0xFFFFFFFC is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12697== 
==12697== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==12697==  GPF (Pointer out of bounds?)
==12697==    at 0xDB468B: std::string::string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.7)
==12697==    by 0x1C3AD9E0: chargeRate::chargeRate(chargeRate const&) (in /root//app/libapp++.so)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C9C22: __gnu_cxx::__mt_alloc_base<chargeRate>::construct(chargeRate*, chargeRate const&) (mt_allocator.h:585)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAC9F: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<chargeRate*, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> > >, chargeRate const&) (vector.tcc:284)
==12697==    by 0x1C4CAF9E: std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >::push_back(chargeRate const&) (stl_vector.h:610)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8A03: WebTranslations::getChargeDetails(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<chargeRate, std::allocator<chargeRate> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:427)
==12697==    by 0x1C4C8F83: WebTranslations::getChargeTranslations(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&) (WebTranslations.cpp:1172)
```

The code is just pushing a structure into a vector. The structure has a few string variables in it. Please let me know if the source is required for further debugging.

Some source:

```
typedef struct{
  string chargeType; // The name of the charge type, eg "Date Units"
  string unitSize;
  string rate;
  bool perConnection;
  string cap;
  bool useMaxDailyCharge;
  string maxDailyCharge;
  string identifier;
} chargeRate;
```

getChargeDetails :

```
vector<chargeRate> my_vector;
my_vector.push_back(this->getChargeRateDetails(chargeStructureNames[i]));
```

getChargeRateDetails :

```
where : vector<vector<string> > StringMatrix
StringMatrix *results; //used to retrive results from database.
chargeRate chargeInformation;
...
//populate results, check them
..
chargeInformation.chargeType = (*results)[FIRST_ROW][CHARGE_TYPE];
return chargeInformation;
```

Edit : I am aware this is returning a "copy" .. this is done test out a few things, i am inserting the same into a copy of vector passed by reference.

Cheers!

Comment: the source would greatly simplify debugging.

Comment: it seems like a problem in copy constructor of chargeRate class, push_back() makes a copy of the struc, therefore, you may be deallocating some related object in one copy and then using it in the newly created copy

Comment: the `chargeRate` struct doesn't contain a copy constructor referencing `__atomic_add`.  This does not compute.

Comment: I am sorry i fail to understand, i.e there should be a default provided by the compiler as i understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `getChargeRateDetails` returns by reference you are trying to use a reference to a variable that is already out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your copy constructor doesn't do the right thing.  In order to push an element onto a vector, a copy of your `chargeRate` is created.  At first sight,

```
at 0xDD0725: __gnu_cxx::__atomic_add(int volatile*, int)
chargeRate::chargeRate(chargeRate const&)
```

Tells me that the `chargeRate` copy constructor tries to add something to an uninitialized variable (pointed at by the `int volatile*` argument of `__atomic_add`.

Probably, you are `__atomic_add`ing something to an uninitialized member variable.

```
StringMatrix *results;
```

Seems intended to refer to an array of `string`s.  Chances are that the `StringMatrix` is not initialized well.  Hence, the first row may contain an uninitialized `string`-like piece of memory, that is used to copy-construct the `chargeType` member of your new object.

The `string` class contains a reference counter that needs to be increased when a new `string` points to the same data, so this may make sense.

You can verify this by (temporarily) assigning e.g. an empty string instead of `(*results)[FIRST_ROW][CHARGE_TYPE]`.

Comment: True , currently my structure does not have a copy-const defined. I am depending on a bit-bit copy of the same.

Comment: +1 Uff! good analythical skills :-). For myself, If I see sth. like typedef struct{ bool.., std::string... } myStruct; I stop reading code further. It is simply not worth it.

Comment: @Valentin Heinitz , thanks, i wish for world peace and clean code base too... sadly we both know that is not going to happen. We make mistakes, we clean up mistakes others made and learn on the way... but thanks for your opinon.

Comment: @xtofl: I am printing the structure variables before and after returning and the contents seem to be fine... which would be sufficient to say the stringmatrix is returning correct values. String matrix is actually defined as : vector<vector<string> > StringMatrix

Comment: @Ricko M: before and after returning... `chargeRate` is an object local to the `getChargeRateDetails` function, and is not valid 'after returning'.  Unless you're returning it by reference (cfr @sth's answer). I think you should try to find out when the problem disappears, and analyze it further from there.

Comment: Thanks i understand , (un)luckily the object was valid on return but not when a push_back is done... i'll restructure the source and give it another shot..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on in your application, but maybe it has to do with (not) using back_inserter?

there is a good example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/).